# Expand all properties when calling get-msoluser

Tags: c#, powershell

In previous versions of PowerShell I could reliably call
Get-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName someUser@example.com and expect to retrieve the full object graph in c#
including all collections and complex types.

In PowerShell version 7.1. When I call this method it only retrieves a string representation of the underlying type. Simple types are shown as expected.

My only dependency at this time is
System.Management.Automation" Version="7.1.0"

Sample properties from calling Get-MsolUser

```
"Licenses": [
    "Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense",
    "Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense",
    "Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense"
  ],
"StrongAuthenticationMethods": [
    "Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod",
    "Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod"
  ],
  "StrongAuthenticationPhoneAppDetails": [
    "Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationPhoneAppDetail"
  ],
  "StrongAuthenticationProofupTime": null,
  "StrongAuthenticationRequirements": [
    "Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement"
  ],
  "StrongAuthenticationUserDetails": "Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails",
```

How do I go about loading the details of MsolUser in 7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PowerShell version 7 and later [do not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/connect-to-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide#connect-with-the-microsoft-azure-active-directory-module-for-windows-powershell) the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell module and cmdlets with Msol in their name. For PowerShell version 7 and later, you have to use the [Azure Active Directory PowerShell for Graph module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) or Azure PowerShell.

The approximately equivalent capability you're looking for in the above example is available in [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: Microsoft Graph would certainly be preferable, for the longest time it wasn't available in that sphere but if it's there it will certainly be welcome.